# How to check if product from category is in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to have my checkout show a couple of form fields only if the customer has a product from a certain category in their cart. So far I was able to get half way using code I found on wordimpress. I added the bit towards the end to check for the category and when I ran it it worked, but then timed out before the rest of the page loaded.

```
<?php
function wordimpress_is_conditional_product_in_cart( $product_id ) {
//Check to see if user has product in cart
global $woocommerce;

//flag no book in cart
$book_in_cart = false;

foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
    $_product = $values['data'];
        $terms = get_the_terms( $_product->id, 'product_cat' );

            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                $_categoryid = $term->term_id;
            }

    if ( $_categoryid === 27 ) {
        //book is in cart!
        $book_in_cart = true;

    }
}

return $book_in_cart;

}
?>
```

Is there a better way to do this, or a way to do this that actually works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a memory issue. Once I upped the allotted memory for wordpress it worked without issue. I will leave this here incase someone else runs into this issue.